# "Just to clarify" vs "just For clarify" vs "just for clarification"

Tags: phrase-usage, usage

I'd like to know what of the following phrases is appropriate in this scenario:
I meet someone that talks to me about programming languages (computers) and based on that I think that he assume that I'm a programmer too. Then I have to choose one between the following:

> 1. **Just to clarify**, I'm not a programmer.
> 2. **just for clarify**, I'm not a programmer.
> 3. **just for clarification**, I'm not a programmer.

Which one is correct, if any?

Comment: Since for is a preposition. It shouldnt take a verb as a complement.

Answer (score 6):

Point 1 is correct and is often used in regular conversation.

Point 2 is incorrect and never used in conversation.  However what is often said is "just for **clarity**...", which is correct.

Point 3 is correct and sometimes used in conversation although not as common as point 1, or the phrasing "just for clarity".

Comment: So basically when you say "in regular conversation" you negate for example writing. Isn't it?

Comment: None of the options is really appropriate in formal writing, but writers sometimes use them when a less formal style is desired. Formally, they are saying that the only reason I am not a programmer is in order to provide clarification, but that is not what anyone would understand any of those sentences to mean.

Comment: What sentences 1 and 3 are understood to mean is something like, "I am going to make a statement now _just to clarify_ other things I have said or will say, and that statement is: _I'm not a programmer._"

Comment: @DavidK: Those statements (except for #2) are really not out of bounds in formal writing. (And who's talking about formal writing here anyway? OP mentioned a casual conversation). And your logic is somewhat twisted when you say "that is what anyone would understand" ... in fact, you have it backwards. That is the *first* thing people would understand. "Just to clarify" is an adverbial phrase, similar in meaning to *honestly*: "Honestly, I'm not a programmer."

Answer (score 2):

Of your sentences

> **Just to clarify**, I'm not a programmer.
>   **Just for clarification**, I'm not a programmer.

are correct and appropriate.  If it is a very serious matter or very formal, you might also say

> **Just to be clear**, I'm not a programmer.

In a legal situation, you might say

> **To remove any doubt**, I am not a programmer.

these all sound very formal.

However, If you want to be less formal and more light hearted, you could say

> **You know**, I'm not really a programmer.
>   **Sorry, but** I'm not a programmer.

Comment: The normal legal expression is **for avoidance of doubt** http://www.weagree.com/book/26-For+the+avoidance+of+doubt,+....html

Answer (score 2):

**clarify** is a verb. In a context like this, you need to put an infinitive-marker **to** in front of it.

**clarification** is a noun. You link extra nouns to a sentence with a preposition, for example **for**.

1. correct: you have **to** + verb.
2. incorrect: you have **for** _ verb.
3. orrect: you have **for** + noun.